# How do quantum field theories relate to one by one particle diffraction experiments through two or more slits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, wave-particle-duality

In particles diffraction experiments in which the particles are fired one at a time through two or more slits how second quantization and path integrals approach the fact that the minimum uncertainty width of the envelope of the particle's wave packet can change instantaneously so that it fits through one or through the two slits if the particle's information is 'exposed' or if it is not?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/343237/