# Does particle creation and annihilation in QFT correspond to changing eigenvalues?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, second-quantization

If I understood correctly from Griffiths' explanation of the ladder operators as applied to the quantum harmonic oscillator, the ladder operators represent increasing/decreasing the energy level of the wavefunction and this happens by increasing/decreasing the eigenvalues.  I've also seen it said in some other physics SE threads that, mathematically, the ladder operators are the same as the creation and annihilation operators, but that they mean different things.

My understanding is that the ladder operators are applied to wavefunctions, while the creation and annihilation operators are applied to fields.  And if I understand correctly from Wikipedia, in the context of QFT, a field is essentially a sum of tensor products of Hilbert spaces.  My question then is, similarly to how applying a ladder operator to a wavefunction in QM raises/lowers the wavefunction's eigenvalue, does creating/destroying a particle in QFT correspond to raising/lowering some eigenvalue of the field?

Comment: this answer of mine might help  in understanding the concept of field in quantum mechanics https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/343237/how-does-the-wave-particle-duality-fit-with-quantum-field-theory/343345#343345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear field equations are usually reduced to a system of oscillators, each oscillator corresponding to a particular field mode (essentially an eigenstate.) We then refer to a *particle* as the number of excitations in each mode, i.e., the quantum number of the corresponding oscillator. This interpretation is quite straightforward for the electromagnetic field, since every mode can be characterized by a momentum and polarization, so we can speak of a number of photons having this momentum and polarization.

For those *particles* that call "particles" in classical sense, the same thing happens in the *second quantization* formalism - i.e., once we rewrite the Schrödinger equation (for an arbitrary number of particles) in terms of single-particle eigenstates.

See also: [How does quantization arise in quantum mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/542460/247642)

**Appendix:**
I will try here to cook up a simple example. Suppose we have a many-particle Hamiltonian:
$$
\hat{H} = \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\hat{h_i},$$
which is just a sum of one-particle Hamiltonians
$$
h_i = \frac{p_i^2}{2m}+v(x_i).
$$
We consider only the ground state of the single-particle Hamiltonian,
$$h_i\phi_0(x_i)=\epsilon_0\phi_0(x_i)
$$
(e.g., we could assume that all the other states are much higher in energy and can be disregarded.)
The eigenstates of the full Hamiltonian $H$ are then
$$
\psi_1(x_1)=\phi_0(x_1), \text{(one particle)},\\
\psi_2(x_1, x_2)=\phi_0(x_1)\phi_0(x_2), \text{(two particles)},\\
\psi_3(x_1, x_2, x_3)=\phi_0(x_1)\phi_0(x_2)\phi_0(x_3), \text{(three particles)},\\
...\\\
\psi_3(x_1, x_2, x_3,..., x_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n\phi_0(x_i), \text{(n particles)},
$$
corresponding to (a ladder of) energies
$$
\epsilon_0, 2\epsilon_0, 3\epsilon_0,...,n\epsilon_0.
$$
(For simplicity I neglect the symmetrization and Pauli exclusion principle, obligatory in the case of fermions.)
We can now introduce operators (in the Hilbert space of the multiparticle Hamiltonian $H$) that move us from a single-particle state, to two-particle state, to three-particle state, and so on, every time increasing the energy by $\epsilon_0$. This is quite similar to what ladder operators do in an oscillator, and we could have push this analogy even closer, by showing that the sum and difference of the creation and annihilation operators thus obtained do behave as the position and momentum of an abstract oscillator. This however requires quite a bit of math, and is covered in many books.