# Limit on speed of expansion of the bounded support interval of a position wave function in relativistic quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dirac-equation, klein-gordon-equation

If the support of a quantum mechanical position wave function is a bounded interval, and that interval is expanding or contracting, then I think it cannot change in any direction faster than $c$. To clarify, Consider the following example:

If a one dimensional position wave function (which is not acted upon by any internal or external potential) is measured at $t_0$ and the result is position eigenstate $x = 0$ and then, at $t_0 + \Delta t$, we perform a momentum measurement, resulting in a momentum eigenstate $p_{t_0 + \Delta t}$, then at $t \ge (t_0 + \Delta t)$, the position wave function is a plane wave and the length of the interval of its support cannot excede $(|p_{t_0 + \Delta t}|( (t - (t_0+ \Delta t)) + c \Delta t)$, which cannot excede $c( t - t_0)$.

*My question is*, if the above is true (which I would think it is), then if the support of a position wave function is a bounded interval, does the Klein-Gordon equation, or Dirac equation, limit the speed of the expansion or contraction of that interval, in any direction, to being no faster than $c$?

Comment: I probably could have simplified my example: if a one dimensional position wave function (which is not acted on by any internal or external potential) is measured at $t_0$ and the result is position eigenstate $x=0$ then, at $t \ge t_0$, the momentum is completely unknown but the support of the position wave function, for $t \gt t_0$, can be no greater than the interval $[-c(t - t_0), c(t-t_0)]$ and the interval grows in each direction ($+$ and $-$ directions) at a rate that is no greater than $c$.

Comment: For a solution $\psi(x)$ of the Klein-Gordon or Dirac equation, $|\psi(x)|^2$ doesn't represent the probability density for detecting a particle at $x$. The question seems to assume that it does. The appropriate framework for relativistic quantum physics is relativistic quantum field theory (QFT), in which a "solution" of the Klein-Gordon or Dirac equation is a *field operator* that *acts on* states, and local observables are constructed from field operators.

Comment: In relativistic QFT, a single particle cannot be localized in a strictly bounded region of space. One way to see this is via the Reeh-Schlieder theorem, as I reviewed in my answer to [What's the physical meaning of the statement that “photons don't have positions”?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/492711). For more quantitative detail, see the answers to [The concept of particle in QFT](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/163691) and [Getting particles from fields: normalization issue or localization issue?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/343516)